# Merging a List<string> into another one alphabetically

Tags: c#, list, alphabetical

Say I have a (not so well ordered) master list:

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string> { "AB2", "AB1", "AB3", "BB3", "BB2", "BB1" };
```

I want to add another list to it in alphabetical order. For example, if I have

```
List<string> list2 = new List<string> { "AA1", "AA2", "BA1", "BA2" };
```

The merged list would be

```
List<string> listMerged = new List<string> { "AA1", "AA2", "AB2", "AB1", "AB3", "BA1", "BA2", "BB3", "BB2", "BB1" };
```

So the rule, in loose terms, would be: for each element of the master list, loop the second list and insert each element that is found alphabetically before.

How can I achieve this? I don't want the first list to be sorted, I just want to insert the second one in it ordered accordingly.

Comment: If the first list is not sorted, and you want it to remain not sorted, it makes no sense at all to think you can merge another sorted list into it. Or at least, the "sorted" aspect of the second list is completely irrelevant. Please fix your question so that it includes a [mcve], along with a detailed explanation of what that code does, how that's different from what you want, and what _specifically_ you need help with. As stated now, your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Dmitry: from the post: _"I don't want the first list to be sorted"_. The comments aren't for answering questions anyway, but your proposed answer in your comment clearly violates the stated requirements. Sorting the concatenation of the two lists is effectively the same as sorting the first list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will give you the output you asked for.

For each item in the second list, it will compare it to an item from the first list, moving front to back through the first list. If the comparison is positive, so B > A, it will keep iterating. Otherwise, it will stop and insert into the first list before the item it compared to.

```
var list1 = new List<string> { "AB2", "AB1", "AB3", "BB3", "BB2", "BB1" };
var list2 = new List<string> { "AA1", "AA2", "BA1", "BA2" };

foreach (var item in list2)
{
    var index = 0;
    while (index < list1.Count && item.CompareTo(list1[index]) > 0)
    {
        index++;
    }
    list1.Insert(index, item);
}
```